# Can I implement the three layer architecture in making UML Class Diagram?

Tags: c#, architecture, uml, class-diagram

I am tasked to make a UML Class Diagram of Online Ordering Sytem of a pizza parlor. I made a Class Library:

```
public class Customer : IAdd, IUpdate, IDelete, IView
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerContact { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public bool hasPalmCard { get; set; }

    public void Add()
    {
        //code to add customer goes here
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //code to update customer goes here
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        //code to delete customer goes here
    }

    public void View()
    {
        //code to view customer list goes here
    }
}

public class Product : Category, IAdd, IUpdate, IDelete, IView
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }

    public void Delete()
    {
        //code to delete product goes here
    }

    public void View()
    {
        //code to view product list goes here
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //code to update product goes here
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        //code to add product goes here
    }
}

public class Category : SubCategory
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class OrderList : Product, IComputeSubtotal
{
    public int OrderListID { get; set; }
    public int OrderQuantity { get; set; }

    public decimal subtotalPrice;

    public decimal getSubtotal(decimal pricePerProduct)
    {
        return subtotalPrice += pricePerProduct * OrderQuantity;
    }
}

public class PurchaseOrder : OrderList, IComputeTotal
{
    public int PurchaseOrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseOrderDateTime { get; set; }

    public decimal totalPrice;

    public decimal getTotal(decimal subtotalPrice)
    {
        return totalPrice += subtotalPrice;
    }
}

public class Receipt : PurchaseOrder, IComputeTotal
{
    public int ReceiptNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceiptDateTime { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
    public decimal CashRender { get; set; }

    decimal IComputeTotal.getTotal(decimal serviceCharge)
    {
        return totalPrice += serviceCharge;
    }
}

public class ReceiptWithChange : Receipt, IComputeChange
{
    public decimal Change { get; set; }

    public decimal getChange()
    {
        return Change = CashRender - totalPrice;
    }
}

interface IAdd
{
    void Add();
}

interface IUpdate
{
    void Update();
}

interface IDelete
{
    void Delete();
}

interface IView
{
    void View();
}

interface IComputeSubtotal
{
    decimal getSubtotal(decimal price);
}

interface IComputeTotal
{
    decimal getTotal(decimal price);
}

interface IComputeChange
{
    decimal getChange();
}
```

My professor wants me to implement the 3-layered architecture: Data, Business and UI/Presentation. Is that even possible since I am only making a class library and this was supposed to be used by another programmer? If that is possible, how can I implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you asked your professor for clarification or guidance on what he expects?  It sounds like there's a misunderstanding of the assignment.

Comment: How is this a diagram?

Answer (score 1):

You are kind of right, you can't possible structure those couple of classes in 3 tiers, simply because each tier of a 3-tier architecture has its purpose (you named them: UI, logic and data).

All your classes clearly belong to **business (or logic) layer**. Their methods should somehow access the data (through the **data layer**). They are themselves accessed from the **UI layer**.

So, I suspect your professor wants something like this:

[image]

Each package represents a tier in 3-tier architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can precise your model by extending with deployment diagram to depict, that definitions are implemented as database procedure, web application objects or html code. Etc.